# Is alcohol really haram?

Tags: halal-haram

As far as I know, Jews and Christians believe alcohol is permitted and in Quran, Al-Maidah, verse 5, it says the food of people of the book (Jews and Christians and Sabians) is permitted to you, link to the verse : https://quran.com/5:5

Comment: And what does Quran Al-Maidah, verse 90  (https://quran.com/5/90) say?

Comment: I believe it's about (permissible) meat. There's many tafseer on the verse, And Allah knows best

Comment: In verse [5:3](https://legacy.quran.com/5/3) Allah declared the religion as perfected after mentioning what is allowed and what not. Therefore 5:3 could be regarded as overruling 5:5 or explaining missing details.

Answer (score 1):

Food of the people of the book is permitted as long as it dosnt go over the islamic rulings, like pork could also count as food of the people of the book but is still forbidden so as long as it is permitted in islam then eating it if someone makes you lets say beef then it is permitted to eat.

It clearly states in the quran

> O believers! Intoxicants, gambling, idols, and drawing lots for decisions1 are all evil of Satan’s handiwork. So shun them so you may be successful. [Source](https://quran.com/5/90)

So alcohol in islam is not permitted and consuming it is a big sin.